# Renaming output file when running parallel processing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, operating-system, file-rename

I want to run a script that generates an output file, let's say it is called 'output', in parallel. How can I rename the output files so it is not overwritten? Such as generating them as 'output-1', output-2' etc. Ideally it is dynamic enough such that running the script again does not overwrite the existing outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a random filename:

```
import uuid

filename = f"output-{uuid.uuid4()}"
# use filename
```

Comment: should I put it in the _main_ area?

Comment: Yes, the import goes to the top, and then the filename part where ever you now have your filename definition.

Comment: It does not seem to do what I expected as it seems to be renaming only the final overwrite, so the other files generated by the parallel threads are gone

Comment: the relevant code:

    `if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1)
    func = partial(dyosSim.main, m)
    p.starmap(func, product(cont, ftop))
    filename = str(n)+f"output-{uuid.uuid4()}"
    orig = 'outputPyDyos'
    os.rename(orig, filename)`